# Returning large data sets with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been working on a basic class to handle most of my simple MySQLi queries (e.g. simple select froms), and have run into a bit of an issue related to how I've been returning the data thus far. Here is an example of a function in question:

```
public function selectFromWhere($conn, $columns, $table, $where, $vars, $limit) {
    $sql = "SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s%s";
    $l = ($limit == 0) ? '' : " LIMIT " . $limit;
    $sql = sprintf($sql, $columns, $table, $where, $l);
    if($query = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $a = $this->parameterizeArray($vars);
        if (call_user_func_array(array($query, "bind_param"), $this->refValues($a))) {
            $data = array();
            $query->execute();
            $row = $query->get_result();
            while($r = $row->fetch_assoc()) {
                array_push($data, $r);
            }
            if (count($data) == 1 && $limit == 1) {
                $data = $data[0];
            }
            return $data;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function works splendidly, taking an array of variables and formatting them to work with bind_param. The problem is a fairly glaring one, the fact that I add each row to an array, and then return that array. (if the limit is set as 1, just return a simple associative array) I know this is terrible practice and didn't think much of it when I was creating the function, however I've just run into the obvious memory problem.. large data sets take up way too much memory and cause issues. (e.g. hitting the set php memory limit)

The idea is to return an array with each row inside it as an array, so that I can simply run a foreach on it when I need to. This is to avoid having to bother with the same 4-5 MySQLi lines for each and every single query.

Should I simply return the fetch_assoc() response and run a while loop in my code that uses this function instead of a foreach loop? That's the only solution I'm seeing, I just wanted to post here and see if anyone has had similar adventures and could share some insight.

Answer (score 0):

First the answer to your question.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

```
$row->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

or if by your question you wanted it returned as a simple array rather than an associative array

```
$row->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Second you should not be repeating lines of code, had this function not existed, or if I misunderstand your question

```
$row = $query->get_result();
return arrayMyData($row)
...
function arrayMyData($row){
  $data = array();
  while($r = $row->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($data, $r);
  }
  if (count($data) == 1 && $limit == 1) {
    $data = $data[0];
  }
  return $data;
}
```

should be a representation of what you should be doing, don't repeat yourself.

EDIT
If we want to go further and deal with the memory problem assuming that you are working on each line independently

```
$row = $query->get_result();
return arrayMyData($row, 'myNumberCruncher')
...
function arrayMyData($row, $func){
  $data = array();
  while($r = $row->fetch_assoc()) {
    /*array_push($data,*/ 
    $func($r);
    /*);*/
  }
  if (count($data) == 1 && $limit == 1) {
    $data = $data[0];
  }
  return $data;
}
function myNumberCruncher{
...
}
```